# Android Apps wont update

Tags: android

i know that eclipse has a couple of glitches when it comes to updating your app and running it on the emulator, i have tried everything that i have found on the internet. Stopping the adb manually making a new emulator and starting it with "wipe user data" and restarting it even reinstalling all of the programs. What i have noticed is that it updates correctly until i start adding images to the drawable folder. After that it doesn't update at all. Can anybody help me its really frustrating also the pictures show up on the "graphic layout how they are suppose to it just doesn't update.

Comment: Ok i got it i have to use 9-patch images ty, now i just have to learn how to use them haha its all deform, Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

When you add images/resources to the project Eclipse sometimes (always?) doesn't realize anything changed.  So then when you run the project, you are just running the last version.

A simple way around that is to change one character of code, change it back, and then run your project forcing Eclipse to recompile and upload the new project with the new resources to the device/emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use 9-patch images? If yes - they should be valid. Once I added an invalid 9-patch image and as a result my Eclipse failed to build the app while it had not informed me what was wrong, so I spent some long time figuring out what it could be.

Another idea - image file name should only consist of a-zA-Z_ chars. Yes, commonly used '-' (minus) char is not allowed.